# Booting from usb always in nomodeset?

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, nomodeset

I am booting ubuntu 12.04 from a usb made with linux live usb creator.
It is fine as long as I select the nomodeset option at the purple ubuntu screen.

The question is:

How can I set this mode to be the default one so I don't have to do it every time?

If I add the option to `/etc/default/grub` it doesn't do anything and if I

```
sudo update-grub
```

I get this error

```
"/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)."
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you chroot before running update-grub?

Comment: No. I am new to this can you explain a bit better. What does chroot do?

Comment: Ok write down all steps you have done... how you add nomodeset

Comment: I go to /etc/default/grub and i find the line with the options. I add after "quiet splash" "nomodeset". That's all I did actually.

Comment: you want to update grub in your live usb or that on your harddisk?

Comment: on my live usb, I don't have ubuntu on harddisk

Comment: ok chroot /dev/sdx where sdx is your drive then update the grub

Comment: write down the result of `fdisk -l` command

Comment: fdisk -l does not output anything

Comment: and when I try to chroot the sda or sdb it says: chroot: cannot change root directory to /dev/sda: Not a directory

Comment: use sudo  before fdisk -l

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd9fa2484

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2050047     1024000    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2         2050048  1951473663   974711808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1951473664  1953521663     1024000   12  Compaq diagnostics

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 4003 MB, 4003463168 bytes
84 heads, 20 sectors/track, 4654 cylinders, total 7819264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        8064     7819263     3905600    b  W95 FAT32

Answer (score 0):

Boot your machine with Ubuntu Live CD and select Trying Ubuntu without installation option when it is prompted (Live CD mode)

Identify the root partition 
By terminal

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This command will shows all disks connected. The entry having a * near the device name will be the root partition.(urs is sdb1)

Mount the root partition

Create a mounting point

```
mkdir  /mnt
```

Now mount your root partition

```
Sudo mount /dev/sdb1  /mnt
```

Run the following commands to export the pesudo file system of Live CD to your would be root file system soon.

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/dev
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/proc
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/sys
$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Change the root file system of live system to your hard disk

```
$ sudo chroot /mnt
```

update GRUB

```
$ sudo upate-grub
```

Reboot and eject Ubuntu Live CD

Comment: when I use sudo mount /dev/sdb1 / /mnt I get the following output

Comment: Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help
       mount                    : list mounted filesystems
       mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels

Comment: and alot more instructions on how to use mount. After that when I use sudo mount --bind etc it says that /mnt/dev for example does not exist

Comment: There was a typo error so i make a space between sdb1 and / now do it again `sudo mount /dev/sdb1/ /mnt`

Comment: now it moutns but it says : mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist

Comment: you have just to create the directory...check the edits in the answer

Comment: after sudo chroot /mnt this error appears : chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory